# Why display() is throwing a segmentation error in a queue using a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, queue

Below is the implementation of a queue using a linked list.

In the `main()` function `dequeue()` is called after `enqueue(2)`, and it throws a seg error.
However if `dequeue()` is called after `enqueue(5)`. and it throws no error.

Function `display()` will throw seg error after printing 1 and 2 at `temp -> data`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queue
{
    int data;
    struct queue *next;
};
struct queue *QueueNode, *front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *temp;

void enqueue();
void dequeue();
void display();

int main()
{
    enqueue(1);
    enqueue(2);
    dequeue();
    enqueue(3);
    enqueue(4);
    enqueue(5);
    display();

    return 0;
}

void enqueue(int value)
{
    QueueNode = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    QueueNode->data = value;

    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        front = rear = temp = QueueNode;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = QueueNode;
        temp = rear = QueueNode;
    }
}

void dequeue()
{
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    }
    else if (front == rear)
    {
        temp = front;
        front = rear = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

void display()
{
    printf("Displaying queue : \n");
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = front;
        rear->next = NULL;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\n", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you enqueue a value, you set `QueueNode->data = value;`, but what is `QueueNode->next`?

Comment: At `temp->next = QueueNode;` in `enqueue`, what value do you think `temp` has?

Comment: Since you have [both] `front` and `rear` pointers, you don't need/want `temp`. You want your enqueue/dequeue functions to use `front` and `rear`

Comment: There's absolutely no reason for `QueueNode` to be global either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Notice that the first node queued HAS initialized the superfluous `temp`, so subsequent calls would find that variable quite acceptable.

Comment: @Fe2O3: No, they would not find it acceptable. It is not sufficient that it has been assigned a value; it must have a suitable value. The program contains a `dequeue` call, which executes `free(temp);`, followed by an `enqueue` call, which then attempts to use `temp`. In the computation model specified by the C standard, `temp` is then in an *indeterminate* state, not having any specified value. If it did have a value, it would be pointing at the released memory, and using that would have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Fe2O3: This misuse `temp` is in fact the proximate reason for the crash. Although the program does not set the `next` member in `enqueue`, this is effectively harmless, as it is not used prior to being set. The flow of the program is: `enqueue(1)` inserts the first node, leaving its `next` unset but setting `temp` to the new node. `enqueue(2)` inserts a new node and sets the first node, via `temp->next`, to point to the new node. Then `dequeue()` removes the first node and frees it, leaving `temp` pointing to it…

Comment: … Then `enqueue(3);` adds a new node but sets the freed node to point to it, since `temp` is still pointing to that freed node. (This is describing what happens in practice, not what the C standard requires.) At this point, the second node has its `next` member uninitialized. Further `enqueues` add additional nodes whose contents do not concern us. When `display` is called, it prints the value from the second node, 2, and then attempts to follow its `next` member. That member is uninitialized, due to the bad `temp`. Whatever bytes are taken from it and used as an address result in the crash.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Simply setting `temp = rear;` just prior to `temp->next = QueueNode;` or replacing `temp` with `rear` in that line will result in the last node of the queue being properly updated with the address of the new node, and the program will run to completion (albeit only because the final node has a `next` that is a null pointer due to aforementioned of zeros in the allocated memory, so that should be fixed too) and print the expected output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I concede that I had not really studied this code with its 4 flailing pointers. You are correct. Perhaps you will post an answer to this OP... Perhaps I could give your answer an UV...

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  Please, read how to create a [Minimum, Complete and Veriviable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to post code here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `QueueNode` or `temp` to be declared outside of a function. These variables should be local to a function.

The `enqueue` routine in the question fails to set `temp` before using it in `temp->next = QueueNode;`. It will have some value or state resulting from prior calls to other routines. When `dequeue` is called before `enqueue`, this is disastrous for your program because `dequeue` use `temp` to point to the node it is releasing, and it executes `free(temp);`. Then, when `enqueue` is called, `temp` is in an *indeterminate* state. (Per the C standard, when the memory a pointer is pointing to is freed, the pointer itself becomes invalid.) Even if the pointer were valid in the C abstract model, and in practice in simple programs, it would be pointing to the released memory. However, at this point, `enqueue` should be setting the `next` member of the last node in the queue, not the `next` member of a removed node. It fails to set the `next` member of the last node. Later, when `display` attempts to iterate through the queue, it attempts to use the uninitialized `next` member of a node that was added to the queue. That leads to a segment fault.

When adding a node to a data structure, always initialize all members of the node (except for those for which it makes sense not to have a value, such as an optional value that other parts of the node indicate is not currently in use). The code in `enqueue` does not see the `next` member of the new node. Here is a working `enqueue`:

```
void enqueue(int value)
{
    /*  Use local variable to point to new node.

        Use "sizeof *NewNode" instead of "sizeof (struct queue)" so that we
        always get enough memory for the thing the pointer points to even if
        its type is changed in future code edits.

        In C, do not cast the result of malloc.  It will automatically be
        converted to the type of the pointer being assigned or initialized, and
        casting can conceal certain code errors.
     */
    struct queue *NewNode = malloc(sizeof *NewNode);

    //  Set all members of the new node.
    NewNode->data = value;
    NewNode->next = NULL;

    /*  Something "before" the new node should point to it.  That might be
        a prior node or it might be the front-of-queue pointer.
    */
    if (front)
        rear->next = NewNode;
    else
        front      = NewNode;

    //  Update the rear-of-queue pointer.
    rear = NewNode;

    /*  Observe that this routine, excepting comments, is shorter and simpler
        than the original enqueue.
    */
}
```

You can also improve `dequeue` and `display` and remove the `QueueNode` and `temp` variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct queue
{
    int data;
    struct queue *next;
};


struct queue *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;


void enqueue();
void dequeue();
void display();


int main(void)
{
    enqueue(1);
    enqueue(2);
    dequeue();
    enqueue(3);
    enqueue(4);
    enqueue(5);
    display();

    return 0;
}


void enqueue(int value)
{
    /*  Use local variable to point to new node.

        Use "sizeof *NewNode" instead of "sizeof (struct queue)" so that we
        always get enough memory for the thing the pointer points to even if
        its type is changed in future code edits.

        In C, do not cast the result of malloc.  It will automatically be
        converted to the type of the pointer being assigned or initialized, and
        casting can conceal certain code errors.
     */
    struct queue *NewNode = malloc(sizeof *NewNode);

    //  Set all members of the new node.
    NewNode->data = value;
    NewNode->next = NULL;

    /*  Something "before" the new node should point to it.  That might be
        a prior node or it might be the front-of-queue pointer.
    */
    if (front)
        rear->next = NewNode;
    else
        front      = NewNode;

    //  Update the rear-of-queue pointer.
    rear = NewNode;

    /*  Observe that this routine, excepting comments, is shorter and simpler
        than the original enqueue.
    */
}


void dequeue()
{
    struct queue *OldNode = front;

    /*  We do not need to check both front and rear.  If there is no front node
        in the queue, it is empty.
    */
    if (!OldNode)
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    else
    {
        //  Update the front-of-queue pointer.
        front = OldNode->next;

        /*  If there is no node in the queue now, update the rear-of-queue
            pointer.
        */
        if (!front)
            rear = NULL;

        //  Release the node.
        free(OldNode);
    }
}


void display()
{
    printf("Displaying queue: \n");
    if (!front)
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
    else
        /*  Iterate through the queue using a simple for loop:

                Start at the front.

                Continue as long as there is a node.

                After each iteration, proceed to the next node.
        */
        for (struct queue *Node = front; Node; Node = Node->next)
            printf("%d\n", Node->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's a little "heavy handed", below is an annotated revision of the functionality that may prove useful to you.

Significant is the absence of any global variables (and the opportunity to run multiple queues simultaneously), and passing the address of a single struct as a parameter to the "service provider" functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Use typedef to reduce verbiage
typedef struct queue {
    int data;
    struct queue *next; // datatype not yet encountered. Need "struct name"
} queue_t; // Conventional naming using "_t" suffix

// Combine two pointers into one 'object' (Could add counter, if desired)
typedef struct {
    queue_t *head; // use conventional names
    queue_t *tail;
} oneQueue_t;

// for brevity, this trio of functions deliberately omit checking *q != NULL
void enqueue( oneQueue_t *q, int value ) {
    // use calloc for reliable initialisation to nulls
    // it's too easy to add a member and forget to initialize a value
    queue_t *pn = calloc( 1, sizeof *pn );
    if( pn == NULL ) { // ALWAYS test return codes
        // deal with allocation error
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    pn->data = value; // assign known data; the rest is/are NULL'd

    if( q->tail ) // always append to the tail, so test the tail
        q->tail = q->tail->next = pn;
    else
        q->tail = q->head = pn; // first node; assign head too
}

void dequeue( oneQueue_t *q ) {
    if( q->head == NULL ) // report where "soft error" occurred
        printf( "dequeue() -- queue is empty\n" );
    else {
        queue_t *del = q->head; // "del" winks in-and-out of existence
        if( ( q->head = q->head->next ) == NULL ) // last entry??
            q->tail = NULL;
        free( del );
    }
}

void display( oneQueue_t *q ) { // simple traversal
    printf( "Displaying queue...\n" );
    for( queue_t *pn = q->head; pn; pn = pn->next )
        printf( "%d\n", pn->data );
    printf( "End of Queue\n" );
}

// put code for "service functions" ahead of invocations
// definition is then the "func prototype". less maintenance
int main() {
    oneQueue_t q = { NULL, NULL }; // one initialised queue. could have multiple

    dequeue( &q ); // test "illicit" operation
    display( &q ); // test with empty queue
    enqueue( &q, 1 );
    enqueue( &q, 2 );
    display( &q ); // test with two items
    dequeue( &q );
    enqueue( &q, 3 );
    enqueue( &q, 4 );
    enqueue( &q, 5 );
    display( &q ); // penultimate test

    while( q.head ) // memory leaks are bad
        dequeue( &q );

    display( &q ); // final test
    dequeue( &q ); // test "illicit" operation

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
dequeue() -- queue is empty
Displaying queue...
End of Queue
Displaying queue...
1
2
End of Queue
Displaying queue...
2
3
4
5
End of Queue
Displaying queue...
End of Queue
dequeue() -- queue is empty
```

If all those '&' in `main()` are making you nervous, here's the body of `main()` using an extra pointer for appearances sake.

```
{
    oneQueue_t q = { NULL, NULL }, *qp = &q; // one initialised queue. could have multiple

    dequeue( qp ); // test "illicit" operation
    display( qp ); // test with empty queue
    enqueue( qp, 1 );
    enqueue( qp, 2 );
    display( qp ); // test with two items
    dequeue( qp );
    enqueue( qp, 3 );
    enqueue( qp, 4 );
    enqueue( qp, 5 );
    display( qp ); // penultimate test

    while( qp->head ) // memory leaks are bad
        dequeue( qp );

    display( qp ); // final test
    dequeue( qp ); // test "illicit" operation

    return 0;
}
```